# How do I make this card using html and css?

Tags: html, css

[solo linktree example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ckNi.jpg)

This is one of the examples in solo.to linktree. I would like to ask how I can use html and css to present it.

I originally planned to use

```css
float:left;
```

to make the image float so that the border of the text can cut through the image, but in the end I found that the image would only be pushed out by the border. I also tried to find out if there is a similar one Looks like it, but can't find it

Comment: see my solution, you'll get exactly what you're expecting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My try (with different font and arrow)

- Pure HTML/CSS
- Zero images

```css
div#main {
  position:relative;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 200px);
  margin-top:50px;
}
div#main div#orange-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: -40px;
  background-color: color(srgb 0.9694 0.4055 0.3275);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px color(srgb 0.9694 0.4055 0.3275 / 0.20);
  z-index: 3;
 }
 
 div#main div#orange-box div#rect {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  width: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left:30%;
 }
  div#main div#orange-box div#circle {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left:45%;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
 
 div#main div#text-container {
  position: absolute;
  border:1.5px solid #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px #EEEEEE;
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 
 div#main div#text-container span#arrow {
  position:absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: calc(50% - 14px);
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 28px;
 }
 
 div#main div#text-container span#subscribe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: calc(25%);
  font-family: Avenir Next, Serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #565656;
 }
 
  div#main div#text-container span#patreon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: calc(50%);
  font-family: Avenir Next, Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="orange-box">
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="rect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="text-container">
    <span id="subscribe">Subscribe</span>
    <span id="patreon">patreon.com</span>
    <span id="arrow">→</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to your problem. Please go through the code.

Add this code to your HTML & CSS File.
Don't Forget to run Code Snippet in full page.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap'); 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

body{
    display: flex;
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    margin: 150px;
    
    
  }
  
  .card{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eaf5f0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 35px 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .imgBx img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .imgBx{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.35);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  
.card .content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .card .content .details{
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  #arrow{
    background-color: #eaf5f0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(160px);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    
  }
```

```html
 

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title></title>
  <link href="q1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta content="" name="description">

  <meta content="" property="og:title">
  <meta content="" property="og:type">
  <meta content="" property="og:url">
  <meta content="" property="og:image">

  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon" sizes="any">
  <link href="/icon.svg" rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml">
  <link href="icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <link href="site.webmanifest" rel="manifest">
  <meta content="#fafafa" name="theme-color">
</head>

<body>
<div class="card">
  <div class="imgBx">
    <img src = "https://profilmmakerapps.com/images/patreon.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="details">
      <h2>Subscribe<br><span>patreon.com</span></h2>
    </div>
    <button id="arrow">></button>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overlapping effect by employing `position: relative` and fine-tuning the image placement through adjustments to the top, bottom, left, or right properties.

demo
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-aynypc?file=styles.css)